# Solving an Initial Value Problem Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So, I have the problem of $dy/dx=(3x^2-e^x)/(2y-5)$ and $y(0)=1$

I have solved the problem getting $$y= \frac{5 \pm \sqrt{13 +4x^3- 4e^x} }{2}$$

How do I solve for the Interval of Validity? I have to write down an inequality for which determines the interval on which the solution is valid.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: well I thought it would just be y does not equal 5/2, right? Because of the domain and range of it. I don't know if im thinking too simple or if that is the correct answer. And for x it would −∞<x<∞

Comment: The only restriction on $y$ is that the quantity inside the square root must be equal to or greater than $0$. This requires thst $x$ be in a certain interval, which is what you need to figure out

Comment: You’ll want to choose the sign in the $\pm$ term that makes the initial value what you need.

Comment: I think you have a typo. The $-4x^3$ term under the radical should be $+4x^3$.